# Logging all the queries in postgres

Tags: postgresql, log

I am using Postgres as my Database. I need to know whether I can extract all the queries that got executed with out logging them as logging all the queries will degrade the performance of database. So, provide a way I can get all the queries that got executed with out logging the queries.

Comment: So, you're looking for magic?  If you don't log what is ran, how can you know what has been ran?

Comment: Ok then How a tool that monitors the database(profiler) like SQLProfiler in case of postgres gets all the queries with out using log files...please let me know..

Comment: Point is something must be running to gather those statistics or you won't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not logging the queries, there is no chance. However, if you are looking for some statistics to find e.g. queries which are executed very often and therefore an optimization could make sense: Checkout [pg_stat_statment-extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgstatstatements.html)

Comment: pg_stat_statements works fine..But, it will not give the details like processid(pid) of process which executed the query...(or) client_address etc..Help me on finding them..

Comment: Yes. The only way doing this I know of is logging the queries or maybe the wireshark approach is working. Didn't know it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by capturing the traffic with tshark and some filters :
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/p/pgsql.html

It will not be very proper but should work.

Comment: This will only work if not using SSL encrypted connection, right?

Comment: yes, only without ssl.